# Dynamic Bootstrap Tab Content with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, each

I am attempting to pull in data into my bootstrap tabs. I am having trouble defining the ID's of the Tabs and how to call the data correctly.

The reason is that my tabs are defined through a loop for days of the week

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <% 0.upto(7.to_i).each do |day_count| %>
    <li>
      <a href="#<%=day_count%>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <%= (Date.today + day_count.days).strftime('%A') unless day_count == 0 || day_count == 1 %>
        <% if day_count == 0 %><b>Today</b><% elsif day_count == 1 %>Tomorrow<% end %> 
      </a>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This works great and I have defined the href as 'day_count' (loop from 0-6) which i thought I could refer to in the content. **Any ideas on how to finish this?**

The below is not quite there obviously as it renders 7 paragraphs of text for each tab:

```
<% 0.upto(7.to_i).each do |id_count| %>
  <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="<%= id_count %>">
      <p>TAB CONTENT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix... Open to any better answers! :)

```
  <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <% 0.upto(7.to_i).each do |id_count| %>
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="<%= id_count %>">
        <p>TAB CONTENT</p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```